# Mule Server 3.7 > Anypoint Studio > AMQP > Handle request timeout

Tags: mule, esb, amqp, anypoint-studio

Is there a way how to handle AMQP timeout in Mule? How?

What I want to achieve is:

```
                    -------- ---> (AMQP TIMEOUT?) -> Log: "AMQP timed out..."
Payload -> AMQP -> | Choice |
                    -------- ---> (DEFAULT) -> Log: "AMQP RESPONSE: #[payload]"
```

Hope my illustration is enough. Thanks in advance.

.ubuntux

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience on AMQP but I think you can achieve this if your able to product AMQP timed out error.

Please follow below steps (I guess)

1) Keep the logger component after AMQP endpoint.

2) Add the breakpoint at logger component.

3) Run the project in Debug mode and check the payload and message values at logger component in both cases (AMQP returns success payload and Timed out error).

4) Once your able to identify the paylaod and messages in both cases, add the choice router accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you get any exception the handle the same logic through the exception handling mechanisms

Use a choice exception strategy and then provide the exception name there and if such exception happens then log using the logger .

In this approach you will not need a choice and use the default section of your illustration only in the main flow without choice and the rest of the logic will go into the choice exception strategy .

Please go though this link to know more about choice [exception strategy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/choice-exception-strategy)